# Rails 3 route with json format not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a route that I need to call like so:

```
/images/get_subcollections.json?id=1234
```

I have this in my routes file:

```
resources :images do
    collection do
      get 'get_subcollections'
    end
  end
```

I have this in my controller:

```
def get_subcollections
    collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :layout =>  false, :json => collection.to_json(:methods=>:get_subcollections) }
    end
  end
```

The app just sits there when I call the URL.  The request doesn't get logged or anything.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure it's related to your problem, but it's a bit strange to have an `id` parameter on a `collection` route. It would probably be better to use `collection_id` to be clear that it is not an id for an `image` record.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the route to a match route with an id in the URL (instead of the query string) and it works much better.  I wasn't sure if I could have .json at the end of the id (instead of the action), but it seems like I can.

Comment: Hmm.. hardcoding the query string in the route with `match` is not really a good idea. If you ever add other parameters, and someone puts the query params in a different order, they will get an error.

Comment: I suppose hardcoding "json" to the end of URL does not corresponds to actual ```"format=json"```. What you need to do is send a parameter ```"?format=json"``` in the URL, and tell me if its working now ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected the response using firebug or chrome's dev tools?  Is it just that layout: false is stopping you seeing anything?